# Specify language in queries to Search API

Tags: google-app-engine

When creating a document to add to a search index, you can specify the document language.  I've done this, but would now like to query only those docs in a specific language.  Is this possible?  I assumed it would be trivial (and documented), but I can't find how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can currently, but I haven't seen anything explicitly saying that. I'm implying from these sentences that the language field is for their use and not for querying.

The language parameter for [search.TextField](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/fieldclasses#Field_language):

```
Two-letter ISO 693-1 language code for the field's content, to assist in tokenization. If None, the language code of the document will be used.
```

And [Building Queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Building_Queries):

```
Search supports all space-delimited languages as well as some languages not segmented by spaces (specifically, Chinese, Japanese, Korean, and Thai). For these languages, Search segments the text automatically.
```

They need to know the language so they know how to parse it into words.

My plan is to just add an additional field to my search documents that has the same value as the language field. It's slightly redundant, but simple to do.

```
search.Document(
   fields = [
      ...,
      search.TextField(name='language', value=lang),
    ],
    language = lang,
)
```